# Javascript weather script

Tags: javascript, iphone, xml, weather

I'm trying to build a lockscreen for my iPhone, and I want it to have a weather portion. I know you can do this with yahoo's weather xml, but I don't know how to display the stuff I need. I don't really like asking for help with questions like this, but I honestly don't understand it at all. Is there a way I could  get the current weather and temperature in my town via [this xml](http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?p=USNY0379&u=f), and then use the current weather and display an image and termerature? For instance, if it was sunny, it would display a picture of a sun and below that it'd say the degrees it is out. If anyone could help it all it would be GREATLY appreciated. Oh, and I can't use PHP for this, just javascript or jQuery.

Comment: Is it actually possible to run JavaScript via the iPhone's lock screen?

Comment: @Colin Surprisingly, yes! The whole lockscreen is HTML, CSS, and Javascript.

Comment: It seems you'll need to create a proxy for it because of the access policy.Also on this [example](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/connection/weather.html) it uses a php proxy.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't have any problem using something else other than yahoo here is a good plugin which you can use : http://paperkilledrock.com/2010/06/how-to-display-weather-with-jquery/

Comment: Link is broken.